# Query in other query

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
fk_activity_id AS KeyId,
data,
created_on,
(SELECT 
        data
    FROM
        activity_queue_data
    WHERE
        activity_queue_data.key = 'data'
            AND activity_queue_data.activity_data_id = KeyId) 
FROM
    activity_queue_data
WHERE
    activity_queue_data.key = 'filename'
LIMIT 100;
```

The problem i have a table like this:

[image: table description]

And the info its storage like this

[image: table content]

This is a legacy code, i can not modificated this code...

But i want get the content and the name for each file in the same query... any idea...???

Answer (score 0):

If your query is what you intend, you need table aliases and qualified column names:

```
SELECT aqd.fk_activity_id AS KeyId, aqd.data, aqd.created_on,
       (SELECT aqd2.data
        FROM activity_queue_data aqd2
        WHERE aqd2.key = 'data' AND
              aqd2.activity_data_id = aqd.KeyId  -- this might be backwards
       ) as other_data
FROM activity_queue_data aqd
WHERE aqd.key = 'filename'
LIMIT 100;
```

Some advice:  Use table aliases and qualified column names in any query that references more than one table.  That way, you don't have to think about when to do the right thing.

Comment: i got this response `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'aqd.KeyId' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @aasanchez . . . That was a typo.